# How to kill Windows Update Medic Service

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, services, windows-services

Having extreme difficulties getting Windows to stop auto-restarting my workstation after updates. I've lost so much work I don't even care anymore, I just want to disable the whole thing.

Unfortunately, I cannot permanently disable the Windows Update Service and I think it has to do with another service called Windows Update Medic Service. However, even as an admin I cannot manually stop or disable the service. What do I need to do?

Comment: See this article on how to disable it...https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-medic-service